# When will Protocol v4.0 be enabled on the Live servers?

Tags: api, protocols, opayo

Apologies this is not a code related issue as such.

I have built the integration for protocol v4.0 to handle 3DSv2 but after calling and speaking to SagePay Support they now say it has all be delayed. I then found this online:

> The FCA will not take enforcement action against firms if they do not
>   meet the relevant requirements for SCA from 14 September 2019 in areas
>   covered by the agreed plan, where there is evidence that they have
>   taken the necessary steps to comply with the plan. At the end of the
>   18-month period, the FCA expects all firms to have made the necessary
>   changes and undertaken the required testing to apply SCA.

Source: https://www.fca.org.uk/news/press-releases/fca-agrees-plan-phased-implementation-strong-customer-authentication

Not quite delayed as SagePay had me believe.  So I would like to know when SagePay is actually going to turn this all on at their LIVE servers? Is there an update - does anyone know when this will likely be?

Comment: I spoke with SagePay support end of last week and got told that it should be live by the 14th of September.

Comment: Thanks - You would have thought it would be before the proposed mandatory date!

Comment: Absolutely, especially as the 14th is a Saturday. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why SagePay have dragged their heels with this but wouldn't 3DSv1 be sufficient for SCA, which is available on V3 until the time comes when it will be retired and 3DSv2 is then mandatory unless a transaction is exemptable. I thought the main benefit for 3DSv2 was better conversion as there will be less challenged and a better user experience?

Comment: Yes, you are correct 3DSv1 would suffice. The issue we are facing is that SagePay have sent out many emails to account holders (My clients) stating it all needs to be in place by the 14th. So there are expectations on us now to have this ready.  I wish they would send out further emails information of the delay and clearly stating that 3DSv1, which we have had for years now, would satisfy SCA for the time being.

Comment: I just got of the phone with SagePay support and got told that 3DSv2 is postponed and will not go live on the 14th of September. Emails are send out to the billing email address since the last 2 days. Can anybody confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this again today, and it now seems to work (although the bank I tried fell back to v1).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the latest notification from SagePay by email.

3DSecure v2 will not go live on 14 September 2019.

```
"Last month, the Financial Conduct Authority announced a welcome 18 month 
extension to the 14 September 2019 Strong Customer Authentication deadline
giving businesses, banks and online account providers more time to roll-out 
the next phase in fraud protection technology. Businesses like yours now have 
until March 2021 to become compliant.

At Sage Pay we've been working to minimise the impact for our customers by 
upgrading our systems to support 3D Secure. While we expect a gradual transition 
to SCA enforcement by banks and issuers across the EU, in time for the deadline, 
there are steps we recommend you start to take now to prepare your business."

...

"We'll continue to work closely with acquirers and issuers across the industry to 
confirm 3D Secure 2 timelines applicable to Sage Pay customers. You can check 
our support pages for regular updates on industry developments."

"From 1 February 2020 issuers will begin to step up transactions. As SCA comes 
into force, banks will start to decline transactions that don't have appropriate 
authentication in place."
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I uploaded the new code base to the live sites using SagePay protocol 3.00 and found that the banks haven't asked yet for the challenge password. The payements came through as 3DAUTH. The order record shows 3DSecureStatus = OK.

That's pretty much what I expected from protocol 4.00.

Looks like the banks are on track.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this today on Live. Got the following error:

```
INVALID 3097 : The VPSProtocol value is outside the valid range. Should be between 2.00 and 3.00.
```

So it's not live as yet.

As a result, we contacted our account manager who told us the following:

> We wont be able to put the SCA enabled protocols live until we’ve been given the go ahead from all acquirers, but this is expected in the next few weeks.

So it sounds like it's fairly imminent.